# JasperReports - last line of a table on a page

Tags: jasper-reports

I have a table that gets split onto multiple pages due to it's size. The style of the table doesn't have the border between two rows and when the table gets split the last row doesn't seem right due to the missing bottom border.
I just want the last record to terminate with a border so that the page seems complete.

Is there a way to set the bottom border to the last line on the page or, how should I implement this behavior?

Comment: You can use a horizontal line immediately after the table to achieve this.

Comment: @Praveen But that means the horizontal line has to be in the next band right?

Comment: not like that. You can add the line on the border of the band in which your table belongs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Table column footers repeat just like column headers. By adding a top pen border to the column footer the effect is perfect.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a horizontal line in the border of the band in which you are using the table.

The option for drawing horizontal line is available in Palette.

Answer (score 0):

As per your question i am not totally confident about my answer but may be u can do by just adding one **sub-report** after your table and just put one **line** from pallet in that report may be that will help u to make your report more clear.

Thanks,
 Hiren patel